# Error while building C# project in VS Community (Dependancies Exchange)

Tags: c#, nuget, exchangewebservices, vs-community-edition

This is my first question here. I'm working on a Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio Community (Update 2). I'm building a small service in C# for my company that parses emails from an Exchange web service. In my solution, there are 2 projects: one built from scratch where I create the service and deal with emails, and the other one is a "Visual Studio Installer" that creates a small .exe to install the service with with all its dependencies.

The first project uses `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth` and `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` libraries to communicate and parse emails from an exchange web service. These two dependencies are coming from NuGet. Both projects are built with the 4.5 .Net Framework. The installer has one main output which is the service project and has 4 dependencies:

- Microsoft .NET Framwork.dll
- Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll
- Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
- System.net.HTTP.dll

The service works pretty well and I'm happy with it. I tried to update my code this week to see how I can write in the Windows journal. The issue is that since this week (30/05/2016) I can't regenerate my solution. I can build the first project (service one) and there are no issue but for the second one (installer), 4 warnings show up (both appear twice in DEBUG mode and 3 times in RELEASE mode):

> WARNING: Unable to find dependency
>   'MICROSOFT.IDENTITYMODEL.EXTENSIONS' (Signature='69C3241E6F0468CA'
>   Version='2.0.0.0') of assembly
>   'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll'
>
> WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.IDENTITYMODEL'
>   (Signature='31BF3856AD364E35' Version='3.5.0.0') of assembly
>   'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll'

These warnings explain the fact that the installer don't appear anymore in the DEBUG and RELEASE folder. I reverted the code I wrote and the error is the same. I also tried to create a new solution with the same project as 4.5 Framework basis and with an empty project but with the same dependencies I have the same warnings.

Do you guys have (had?) the same warnings?

Comment: Please help!!! 12 days ago and still no solution neither solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. My solution was saved directly on a remote hard drive. When I built the soution, .net framework was not found (my error). I re-create localy my solution and it works. Hope it will helps others.

Perhaps, I don't know why from one day to another .net was not found. Maybe Windows update has crashed during an update.